# Filter rows in r having same categorical value in all columns and also rows with all different categories

Tags: r, filter

I am attempting to filter rows from following dataset where a,b and c give same answers, and also where a, b and c all give different answers from a category of 3 answers.

### id   A   B   C

11. X1   X2   X3
12. X2   NA   X1
13. X1   X1   X1
14. X2   X1   X3
15. X1   X1   X2

Result for a,b and c giving same answers should be

### id. A B C

13. X1  X1  X1

result for a, b and c all giving different answers should be

### id. A B C

11. X1 X2 X3
12. X2 X1 X3

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is R's [`subset()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/subset) in combination with logical expressions `A==B & B==C`, `A!=B & B!=C & A!=C`?